# How to accumulate (average) data based on multiple criteria

Tags: matlab, pivot-table, average, accumarray

I have a set of data where I have recorded values in sets of 3 readings (so as to be able to obtain a general idea of the SEM). I have them recorded in a list that looks as follows, which I am trying to collapse into averages of each set of 3 points:

[image: Original Table]

I want to collapse essentially each 3 rows into one row where the average data value is given for that set. In essence, it would look as follows:

[image: Desired result]

This is something I know how to do basically in Excel (i.e. using a Pivot table) but I am not sure how to do the same in MATLAB. I have tried using `accumarray` but struggle with knowing how to incorporate multiple conditions essentially. I would need to create a `subs` array where its number corresponds to each unique set of 3 data points. By brute force, I could create an array such as:

```
subs = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3; 4 4 4; ...]'
```

using some looping and have that as my subs array, but since it isn't tied to the data itself, and there may be strange hiccups throughout (i.e. more than 3 data points per set, or missing data, etc.). I know there must be some way to have this sort of Pivot-table-esque grouping for something like this, but need some help to get it off the ground. Thanks.

Here is the input data in text form:

```
Subject  Flow   On/Off   Values
1        10     1        2.20
1        10     1        2.50
1        10     1        2.60
1        20     1        5.50
1        20     1        6.10
1        20     1        5.90
1        30     1        10.10
1        30     1        10.50
1        30     1        10.50
1        10     0        1.90
1        10     0        2.20
1        10     0        2.30
1        20     0        5.20
1        20     0        5.80
1        20     0        5.60
1        30     0        9.80
1        30     0        10.20
1        30     0        10.20
2        10     1        5.70
2        10     1        6.00
2        10     1        6.10
2        20     1        9.00
2        20     1        9.60
2        20     1        9.40
2        30     1        13.60
2        30     1        14.00
2        30     1        14.00
2        10     0        5.40
2        10     0        5.70
2        10     0        5.80
2        20     0        8.70
2        20     0        9.30
2        20     0        9.10
2        30     0        13.30
2        30     0        13.70
2        30     0        13.70
```

Comment: Can you please paste the input data as text too? Also, how do you ger for example output `2.13`? What numbers are averaged there?

Comment: Hi @LuisMendo, thanks for looking at this question. I uploaded the text data just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that

- You want to average based on unique values of the first three columns (not on groups of three rows, although the two criteria coincide in your example);
- Order is determined by column 1, then 3, then 2.

Then, denoting your data as `x`,

```
[~, ~, subs] = unique(x(:, [1 3 2]), 'rows', 'sorted');
result = accumarray(subs, x(:,end), [], @mean);
```

gives

```
result =
    2.1333
    5.5333
   10.0667
    2.4333
    5.8333
   10.3667
    5.6333
    9.0333
   13.5667
    5.9333
    9.3333
   13.8667
```

As you see, I am using the third output of [`unique`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `'rows'` and `'sorted'` options. This creates the `subs` grouping vector based on first three columns of your data in the desired order. Then, passing that to [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) computes the means.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What would be the advantage of using the `'sorted'` type vs. using `'stable'`?

Comment: Without `'sorted'` you don't get the results in the same order you indicate in your question

Comment: Ah nice, thanks very much; very clear and concise way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: I also wonder, @LuisMendo, were I to include another column--for example, date values--how could I do this same procedure, given that I cannot combine a column of dates into an array with the rest of the data?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) like so to maintain the order of your rows of data:

```
[newData, ~, subs] = unique(data(:, 1:3), 'rows', 'stable');
newData(:, 4) = accumarray(subs, data(:, 4), [], @mean);

newData =

    1.0000   10.0000    1.0000    2.4333
    1.0000   20.0000    1.0000    5.8333
    1.0000   30.0000    1.0000   10.3667
    1.0000   10.0000         0    2.1333
    1.0000   20.0000         0    5.5333
    1.0000   30.0000         0   10.0667
    2.0000   10.0000    1.0000    5.9333
    2.0000   20.0000    1.0000    9.3333
    2.0000   30.0000    1.0000   13.8667
    2.0000   10.0000         0    5.6333
    2.0000   20.0000         0    9.0333
    2.0000   30.0000         0   13.5667
```

Comment: Thank you @gnovice for your help; this is really great. I also wonder: do you know what could be done if one of the columns of data was of another data type (i.e. date cells) and thus couldn't be combined into the `data` array, such as in this example?

Comment: @teepee: If you have a date, you can convert it to a numeric value using [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html). Then you can add it as another column in `data`.

Comment: Ah, OK, that's the way to do it. Great, thanks very much. I have already implemented a workaround by compiling the data into a `table`, as `unique()` accepts this type and can spit out the `subs` I need. Is there any particular disadvantage to this approach as an alternative?

Comment: @teepee: No, tables are good ways to collect and display different types of data.

Answer (score 0):

`accumarray` is indeed the way to go. First, you'll need assign an index to each set of values with `unique` :

```
[unique_subjects, ~, ind_subjects] = unique(vect_subjects);
[unique_flows, ~, ind_flows] = unique(vect_flows);
[unique_on_off, ~, ind_on_off] = unique(vect_on_off);
```

So basically, you now got `ind_subjects`, `ind_flows` and `ind_on_off` that are values in `[1..2]`, `[1..3]` and `[1..2]`.

Now, you can compute the mean values in a `[3x2x2]` array (in you example) :

```
mean_values = accumarray([ind_flows, ind_on_off, ind_subjects], vect_values, [], @mean);
mean_values = mean_values(:);
```

*Nota* : order is set accordingly to your example.

Then you can construct the summary :

```
[ind1, ind2, ind3] = ndgrid(1:numel(unique_flows), 1:numel(unique_on_off), 1:numel(unique_subjects));
flows_summary = unique_flows(ind1(:));
on_off_summary = unique_on_off(ind2(:));
subjects_summary = unique_subjects(ind3(:));
```

*Nota* : Also works with non numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try checking out the [findgroups](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) and [splitapply](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) reference pages.  The easiest way to use them here is probably to place your data in a table:

```
 >> T = array2table(data, 'VariableNames', { 'Subject', 'Flow', 'On_Off', 'Values'});
 >> [gid,Tgrp] = findgroups(T(:,1:3));
 >> Tgrp.MeanValue = splitapply(@mean, T(:,4), gid)
 Tgrp =
   12×4 table
     Subject    Flow    On_Off    MeanValue
     _______    ____    ______    _________
     1          10      0         2.1333   
     1          10      1         2.4333   
     1          20      0         5.5333   
     1          20      1         5.8333   
     1          30      0         10.067   
     1          30      1         10.367   
     2          10      0         5.6333   
     2          10      1         5.9333   
     2          20      0         9.0333   
     2          20      1         9.3333   
     2          30      0         13.567   
     2          30      1         13.867
```